# Add images to rightmost column of ListCtrl in wx Python

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

#### TLDR

Is it possible to add an image to the second/rightmost column of a wx.ListCtrl in Python?  This is what I am looking for:

[image]

#### Background

I have a wx.ListCtrl and image list as follows:

```
self.health_grid = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT| wx.LC_ALIGN_TOP)
self.health_grid.InsertColumn(0, heading="Organ")
self.health_grid.InsertColumn(1, heading="Status")
self.health_icons = wx.ImageList(16, 16, False, 0)
self.unhealthy = wx.Bitmap(self.getFilePath("gui" + os.sep + "images" + os.sep + "unhealthy.png"))
self.health_icons.Add(self.unhealthy)
self.healthy = wx.Bitmap(self.getFilePath("gui" + os.sep + "images" + os.sep + "healthy.png"))
self.health_icons.Add(self.healthy)
self.unknown = wx.Bitmap(self.getFilePath("gui" + os.sep + "images" + os.sep + "unknown.png"))
self.health_icons.Add(self.unknown)
self.health_grid.SetImageList(self.health_icons, wx.IMAGE_LIST_SMALL)
```

### Attempt 1

When I add my items in the following way:

```
self.health_grid.InsertImageStringItem(self.health_grid.GetItemCount(), "Heart", 0)
self.health_grid.InsertImageStringItem(self.health_grid.GetItemCount(), "Brain", 0)
self.health_grid.InsertImageStringItem(self.health_grid.GetItemCount(), "Lungs", 1)
self.health_grid.InsertImageStringItem(self.health_grid.GetItemCount(), "Liver", 2)
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

This is to be expected; there is nowhere to explicitly say I want my images to be put into column 1.

### Attempt 2

When I try to add using the append method and setting the bitmap as the second column item as follows:

```
self.health_grid.Append(["Heart", self.unhealthy])
```

It produces this output:

[image]

This is slightly better; at least the reference has been added to the second column but it still isn't what I want.

#### Attempt 2.5

I made a modification in an attempt to make the bitmap display:

```
self.static_unhealthy = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.unhealthy)
self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
self.sizer.Add(self.static_unhealthy, 0)
self.health_grid.Append(["Heart", self.sizer])
```

It produces this:

[image]

Another wrong version.

#### Attempt 3

I tried to explicitly assign the image to the second column and the text to the first in the following code:

```
item = wx.ListItem()
item.SetId(wx.NewId())
item.SetColumn(0)
item.SetText("Heart")
item.SetColumn(1)
item.SetImage(0)
self.health_grid.InsertItem(item)
```

However, this produced this:

[image]

Which I suppose is the closest to what I want out of them all while still failing.

## Finally

Is it possible to produce what I want? Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality I was looking for was not possible under Windows as far as I could find so I went with a different approach as follows.

Used a wx.grid.Grid instead of wx.ListCtrl and implemented an overridden version of wx.grid.PyGridCellRenderer as shown in code excerpt below:

```
import wx.grid as grid
import os
import wx

class healthStatus(wx.Frame):
    organs = ["heart", "lungs", "brain", "liver"]
    health_icons = []
    (row, progress) = (0, 0)

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
    # initialise the frame container
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
    # main gui sizer, shall be the sizer for the window
    self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    self.health_grid = grid.Grid(self)
    self.health_grid.CreateGrid(len(self.organs),2)
    self.health_grid.SetColLabelValue(0, "Organ")
    self.health_grid.SetColLabelValue(1, "Status")
    self.health_grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)

    try:
        self.health_icons.append(self.getFilePath("images" + os.sep + "unknown.png"))
        self.health_icons.append(self.getFilePath("images" + os.sep + "unhealthy.png"))
        self.health_icons.append(self.getFilePath("images" + os.sep + "healthy.png"))
    except Exception as e:
        wx.MessageBox("Cannot load icons. \n Please ensure the images directory has not been moved\n\n"
                      + e.message, "Cannot Load Icons", wx.ICON_ERROR)
    index = 0
    for organ in self.organs:
        self.addItem(index, organ)
        index += 1
    self.main_sizer.Add(self.health_grid, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

    self.testing_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Testing")
    self.testing_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onProgress)
    self.main_sizer.Add(self.testing_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

    self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)
    self.Fit()

    def addItem(self, index, organ):
    self.health_grid.SetCellValue(index, 0, organ)
    self.health_grid.SetCellRenderer(index, 1, BitmapRenderer(self.health_icons[0]))


    def updateProgress(self, index, progress):
    self.health_grid.SetCellRenderer(index, 1, BitmapRenderer(self.health_icons[progress]))
    self.health_grid.Refresh()

    def getFilePath(self, directory):
    curr = os.getcwd() + os.sep
    parent = "listctrlproblem" + os.sep
    parent_offset = len(parent)

    if curr.index(parent) + parent_offset != len(curr + os.sep):
        curr = curr[:curr.index(parent) + parent_offset]
        print curr
    return curr + os.sep + directory

    def onProgress(self, evt):        
    if self.health_grid.GetNumberRows() > 1:
        if self.progress + 1 < len(self.health_icons):
            self.progress += 1
        elif self.row < self.health_grid.GetNumberRows() + 1:
            self.progress = 0
            self.row +=1

    self.updateProgress(self.row, self.progress)


class BitmapRenderer(wx.grid.PyGridCellRenderer):
    def __init__(self, image):
    self.image = image
    wx.grid.PyGridCellRenderer.__init__(self)

    def Draw(self, grid, attr, dc, rect, row, col, is_selected):
    bmp = wx.Bitmap(self.image)
    dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, rect.X, rect.Y)

    def Clone(self):
    return self.__class__()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = healthStatus(None, -1, "Organ Status")
frame.Show(1)
app.MainLoop()
```

This creates the following output on Linux:

[image] [image]

And the following output on Windows:

[image] [image]

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I am seeing an error with this on Windows - it's failing at self.health_grid.SetItem(item) with the message: "C++ assertion "id >=0 && id < GetItemCount()" failed in wxListCtrl::SetItem(): invalid item index in SetItem." When I comment out this line it is adding the images to the left column to the left of the text! Similar problems online are for wxWidgets and SetItem has an additional parameter for index which is missing in wx.Python. Do you know what I should do?

Comment: Post a small runnable example. That would allow me or someone else to give it a try. By the way, which Windows are we talking about (7, 8, 10?) and which version of wx?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Updated :) Thank you :)